# Java : Efficient way of doing operations in a part of an image

Tags: java, opencv

So for most image operations we use `openCV` module. The problem that I am facing is when I want to do operations only at a particular part of the image.

Right now I am traversing through the entire pixel matrix and getting the pixel value using `get` and `put`.

But I know this cannot be an efficient way of doing the operation.

Like if I want to do `Gaussian Blur` only at the eyes then first I have to do Gaussian blurr in an entire copy of the image. Then create a mask using the contour points of the eye, and then traverse through the mask rows and cols to copy the blurred pixel to the original image.

This is a very inefficient approach.
Also, yes we have the concept of submatrix but that will take only rectangular shape which we may not need in all the cases.

So given that we have the mask, the original image, how can we perform operations on that?

PS : Looking for a Java Solution

Comment: What do you mean by  we may not need in all the cases? You mean you don't want to have a rectangle as a shape?

Comment: @ROS_OPENCV Yeah most of the operations that are done are not for a rectangular shape but a different shape.

Comment: So how that shape is defined, you talked about the eye for example?

Comment: @ROS_OPENCV Shape is defined by using some object detection like dlib which gives us points in the image.

Comment: You know where is your object, why don't you apply blurring to their points? you don't have to go through the entire image but go straight to where you want to blur!

Comment: @ROS_OPENCV The coordinates will be given for the border of the contour region and not all the points in an object like eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think there's no simple built-in function to blur a sub region of an image that has a random shapes. I suggest you to follow those steps:

- Define a rectangle shape from the min and max of your contour coordinates points and loop through that rectangle. That will allow you to define a minimum area rectangle for your contour and loop inside it rather than looping through the entire image.
- Then blur only pixels that are inside that random contour. You can use a built-in function to perform a [point-in-contour test c++](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest)

The first step it just a condition in a loop, you don't have to create a mask or anything like that.
Sorry I don't know Java ortherwise I would help you with a piece of code.